# Why can´t I draw text with PIL that includes line break (“\n”)

Tags: python-2.7, text, python-imaging-library, line-breaks

I am trying to create text using PIL. The problem is, that when I want to print a new line (\n), I only get a little box:

Here is the minimal example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

heading1 = 'heading1'+'\n'+'heading1'

path_f = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
font = "Arial.ttf"
path_A = path_f+"/"+font

im1 = Image.open("c.png").resize((300, 300))

new_im=Image.new("RGB",(600 ,500), "white")

new_im.paste(im1, (0,100))

font = ImageFont.truetype(path_A, 20)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(new_im)
draw.text((40,30), heading1, fill= "black", font=font)

new_im.show()
del draw
```

And this is the output I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjBjh.png)

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Because it doesn't interpret control characters.

Comment: But when I run it on a different platform it used to do exactly that, nevermind, the workaround should not be to difficult, so thank you very much for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

"Because it doesn't interpret control characters."
Seems to be an answer to me.